# unittests, assert_function_called() and code flexibility

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

#### This is a question concerning unittests and if/where to draw the line of what to test

Assume there was a function like this:

```
def function():
    do_work()
```

which you had to modify for an issue you worked on to look like this:

```
def function():
    do_work()
    do_additional_work()
```

should you **(A)** add a unittest for `function()` that looks like this:

```
def test_function_called_additional_work():
    mocked_additional_work = mock(function.do_additional_work)
    function()
    assert mocked_additional_work.called_once
```

or should you **(B)** write an integration test that depends on `function()` like this:

```
def test_additional_work_was_done_upon_function_call():
    assert some_client.state == add_work_was_not_done
    function()
    assert some_client.state == add_work_was_done
```

or should you possibly write *both*?

---

My first shot would be to not do **A** and prefer **B** because it

- does **not** enforce a specific implementation of how *additional work* is done, so it will not break on future refactorings that, for example improve speed but have a different calling signature. Instead it will break only when the state that `do_additional_work()` should modify/provide is wrong.
- If you do **A** where do you draw the line? Wouldn't you also need to mock-assert that `do_work()` was called once?

---

However, if `function()` had logic of its own, that you could parametrize, like:

```
def function(conditional):
    do_work() if(conditional) else do_different_work()
```

then I would see a reason to write unittests that do mock-assert both different branches.

---

#### Which tests would you write? (A), (B) or *both*?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, lean towards having your tests loosely coupled as it makes them less fragile. An exception would be when calling `do_work` is important behaviour, not just the state changes that result from it being called. This might be the case in a method that will be overwritten by a subclass say.

That said, tests are there to make your job easier (especially so in terms of maintenance) and sometimes it's not practical to refactor the code just to satisfy the above (for instance, when you're adding tests to legacy code to document behaviour before making changes). In this case, explain your reasoning in a comment in the test and move on.

Comment: > This might be the case in a method that will be overwritten by a subclass say. @Peter Gibson: I agree, if you wanted to assert that a subclass implementation called the superclass method, you would probably want to mock-assert the call. Good point! However, i'd like to exclude that very specific scenario for this question.

Comment: @timmwagener What's the justification for testing those specific functions are called though instead of just testing the results were as expected?

Comment: I'm personally feeling at times, that tests like *(A)* tend to cement-in certain code, especially when testing GUI code. For example when mock asserting certain buttons have been pressed because you added a button in your latest PR etc.

Comment: I honestly doubt the justification of tests like *(A)* more and more. But they continuosly pop up during code review. It is also tempting that when your issue basically was to add this line of code `do_additional_work()` to test it like in *(A)*. However, people also argue that these tests don't really hurt and when in doubt better have too many than too little tests...

Comment: Yes, but having too many fragile tests is a barrier to clean refactoring of code later. The button callback is exactly what I was referring to when I said "when calling `do_work` is important behaviour" - you want to test that the callback was called so add a test for it. I'm not against tests like (A), but I feel they should be justified when used.

Comment: I think we're pretty much on the same page then, which would be: Don't test like in *(A)* unless the call is a result of some logic *(if/else)* or a superclass call you want to enforce *(subclass overrides)* or some other solid legitimization.